# how to share pigpio pins definitions between multiple files

Tags: pigpio

I have generic question on how to share gpio settings across multiple files.

i my main file1.py that runs at loop I have following:

```
import pigpio, time

_gpin = 10
pi_gpio = pigpio.pi()

def _callback(channel, level, tick):
    time.sleep(0.3)
    global latest_status
    if latest_status == pi_gpio.read(channel):
        print("wire interference")
        return
    print("_callback called")
    latest_status = pi_gpio.read(_gpin)


pi_gpio.set_glitch_filter(_gpin, 500)
pi_gpio.callback(_gpin, pigpio.EITHER_EDGE, _callback)
pi_gpio.set_mode(_gpin, pigpio.INPUT)
pi_gpio.set_pull_up_down(_gpin, pigpio.PUD_UP)
latest_status = pi_gpio.read(_gpin)

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    print("running")
    print("gpio mode:{}".format(pi_gpio.get_mode(_gpin)))

pi_gpio.stop()
```

my file2.py is executed via internet (apache) and have following:

```
import pigpio, time
pi_gpio = pigpio.pi()
_gpin = 10
time.sleep(1)
pi_gpio.set_pull_up_down(_gpin, pigpio.PUD_DOWN)
```

Problem is that in second file it is not know what mode PIN is set for, so if I use `pi_gpio.get_mode()` it says PIN is set for OUTput instead of input as defined in first file. Is there any way to keep setup consistency or I need to define pin modes separately in each file?

Comment: Are you sure get_mode() gives the wrong mode?  It reflects the current mode of the GPIO as read from the hardware.  Perhaps you are misinterpreting the value it returns. http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#get_mode

Comment: Valid point, thanks. I discovered, that I have conflicting situation. This GPIO board is also connected remotely to different RPI which is regularly calling `write()` method. This overrides PIN mode from initial 0 to 1

Comment: I generally put that in .h files and include the same file in each compilation. Not sure if it will work on the pi but it does on other systems.